# Multiple jquery min files in a project mark one as important

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, master-pages

In my project I have a master page with a jquery *v1.4*, now I want to add jquery UI to the project so I added a new jquery *v1.11* to the content page. But the UI features does not works in the content page. It think when that the browser is using the older *v1.4* and not 1.11, because when I tried the same content in another page without master page it worked.

So is there a way to fix this issue. I cannot remove the older *v1.4* from the master page. Is there any way to overwrite the older script in the new content page.

When viewed the code in browser:

```
<script src="Js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
\* some body content ... *\
<script src="Js/jquery.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the master page wrap <script src="Js/jquery.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> inside a content placeholder like this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="JqScript" runat="server">        
  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"  EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="id" OnResolveScriptReference="sm_ResolveScriptReference">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/jquery-1.4.min.js" /> 
    </Scripts>
  </asp:ScriptManager>       
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

That way it will by default contain reference to jquery 1.4 and if in your child page you want to replace it just paste that:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="JqScript" Runat="Server">
  <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" /> 
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: In the content page I tried to use the "<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" />" but it did not work .

Then I placed the "<script src="Js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>" in the content page and it worked.
I checked the page source also it has picked only the latest v1.11, and when tried without using the _asp:ScriptManager asp:ScriptReference_ in master page it shows both the Jquery version.

Thank you...

Comment: Also these changes brings a new issue. In a content page that uses the v1.4 I don't specify the script src for the old file as it is already mentioned in the master page. But this doesn't work. "$ is not defined" - No jQuery is loaded. Is there any alternate way you can suggest.

Comment: If a child page want to use JQ 1.4 from master page then on that child page don't define `<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="JqScript" Runat="Server">` at all. Then it will use master page content.

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to show the details from the content page?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: I want to show the details of a content page too and the content page uses old v1.4. So as per your suggestion if I remove the <asp:content> tag then how can I show the content page detail with the master page.

Comment: Your master page should have at least 2 content placeholders, one for jquery script and another one for child page content. If you child page want to use jq 1.4 it should include only one asp:content tag - the one for child page content. I hope its clear enough.

Comment: Ok. I understood it now.
Actually I was adding the script tag src at the 2 content tag and not on the one used for the header. Now it working fine.
Thank you...